# Unsupported URL swift ios sending Http request

Tags: ios, swift, http, request

I'm trying to send an http request in swift. 
I got a method (`sendHttpRequest`) that take as argument a `dictionary<String,AnyObject>` and trying to send a request to localhost with a little server in php. When I tap button that call this function an error occur

> "Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=46.101.145.122/salvobertoncini.com/servo.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=46.101.145.122/salvobertoncini.com/servo.php, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x1763cef0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}})"

[Here is the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxBWe.png)

```
func sendHttpRequests(data : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
{

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    do
    {
        let request = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        let url = NSURL ( string : "127.0.0.1/Server/servo.php")
        let finalRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        finalRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        finalRequest.HTTPBody = request

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(finalRequest){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
            do
            {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                print("Result -> \(result)")
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: For an HTTP request, the URL should start with "http://" (the URL "scheme").

Comment: You should include your code in your question - not in an image, but as code.